# Sort Objects in Array with duplicate values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, multidimensional-array

So I've got an array of objects...

```
var array = [
    {'name':'Jack', 'age':'30', 'weight':'200'},
    {'name':'Ted', 'age':'27', 'weight':'180'},
    {'name':'Ed', 'age':'25', 'weight':'200'},
    {'name':'Bill', 'age':'30', 'weight':'250'}
]
```

...which I know I can sort in ascending order based on their age using...

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a.age) - (b.age);
});
```

Given all this, how can sort by a second parameter only if the ages of two different objects are the same? For instance, in my object, both "array.name = Jack" and "array.name = Bill" have the same age of 30. How can I go in and make absolutely sure that Jack will come before Bill because Jack has a lower weight?

Comment: P.S. I've looked at a bunch of other posts and I really couldn't find a direct answer to this question. I know I'm new to actually posting here and I really did to my research and am not trying to create a duplicate question. Thank you!

Comment: You could use an `if` statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add another sort criteria with chaining with [logical OR `||` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()).

With same age, the difference is zero (a falsy value) and the second part is evaluated.

This method allows to add more sort criteria.

```js
var array = [{ name: 'Jack', age: '30', weight: '200' }, { name: 'Ted', age: '27', weight: '180' }, { name: 'Ed', age: '25', weight: '200' }, { name: 'Bill', age: '30', weight: '250' }];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.age - b.age || a.weight - b.weight;
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: So, the logical OR statement will run only if a.age == b.age? I believe you, but why?

Comment: because if `a.age === b.age` then the difference is zero and the other part with weight is evaluated.

Comment: @DS_ And also if `a.age - b.age` is `NaN`, e.g. some is not defined.

Comment: Makes sense to me and it works like a charm. Thank you so much!